# Monotouch: How to make reusable compound view

Tags: c#, ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, custom-component

I've been trying to create a custom view, by extending from the UIView class. All the examples i find override the Draw method, but i don't need to draw anything I just need to fill the view with other views/controls, when done in the ViewDidLoad in a controller, this works fine, but as soon as I try to make it a Custom class, things go wrong...
As far as i could find, when creating "compound"views one has to override the LayoutSubViews method

what the view has as subviews is irrelevant, this is just an example :

> [Register ("PhotoLabel")]
>
> public class PhotoLabel : UIView
>       {
>
> ```
>   public PhotoLabel () : base () {}
>   public PhotoLabel (IntPtr p) : base (p) {}
>   public PhotoLabel (RectangleF rect) : base (rect) {}
>
>   public override void LayoutSubviews ()
>     {
>         base.LayoutSubviews ();
>         if (Image != null) {
>             AddSubviews (ImageView, Label);
>         } else {
>             AddSubview (Label);
>         }
>     }
>
>
>   public UIImage Image { 
>         get {
>             return ImageView.Image;
>         } 
>         set {
>             ImageView.Image = value;
>             SetNeedsDisplay ();
>         } 
>     }
>
>   UIImageView ImageView { 
>         get {
>             var iFrame = new RectangleF (0, 0, this.Frame.Height, this.Frame.Height);
>             return new UIImageView () {
>                 Frame = iFrame,
>                 ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center,
>                 Image = this.Image.Scale (new SizeF (iFrame.Width, iFrame.Height))
>             };
>         } 
>     }
>
>   public string Text {
>         get {
>             return Label.Text;
>         }
>         set {
>             Label.Text = value;
>             SetNeedsDisplay ();
>         }
>     }
>
>   UILabel Label { 
>         get {
>             var x = Image != null ? this.Frame.Height : 0;
>             var width = Image != null ? this.Frame.Width - this.Frame.Height : this.Frame.Width;
>             var lFrame = new RectangleF (x, 0, width, this.Frame.Height);
>             return new UILabel () {
>                 Frame = lFrame,
>                 ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center,
>                 TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left,
>                 Text = this.Text,
>                 Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize (17),
>                 BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
>             };
>         } 
>     }
> }
> ```

And i tried to use it as such:

> ```
> public override void ViewDidLoad ()
>     {
>         base.ViewDidLoad ();
>         var pLabel = new PhotoLabel () {
>             Frame = new RectangleF (5,5, 100, 60),
>             Image = UIImage.FromFile ("photo.png"),
>             Text = "some text"
>         };
>         this.View.AddSubview (hCell);
>     }
> ```

Guess I'm overlooking something, I know very well how to do that in Android (monodroid), but as I'm pretty new to iOS and MonoTouch, i have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. So if anyone can direct me to or provide me with a working example of this or smth similar, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LayoutSubviews` is meant to arrange your subviews, not to add new ones like you are doing.
In general, you'll only need to override it if you can't get the layout right using auto resizing (`UIView.AutoResizingMask`) or auto layout (available with iOS6).

You are right that you should use `ViewDidLoad` to add subviews to your overloaded view. Be aware that the final layout of your view will only be available after `ViewDidLoad`. This means, you cannot rely on the `Bounds` and `Frame` property. If necessary, do adjustments in `ViewWillAppear`.